# Excel pricing matrix provided without decimals

Tags: excel, matrix, decimal, batch-rename

Is it odd that a pricing matrix is provided without decimals?  For example, a product measuring 23 x 42 shows to be 114 but it's actually supposed to be 11.40.  Another measurement is 28 x 48 and according to the matrix would be 696 but should be 69.6.

1. Why would they do this for any reason (just so I understand why to expect this)
2. Does Excel have an easy way to add a decimal in one space from the right?

I would just do this manually but there are thousands of products.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way using Paste Special.

In my case the number worked out if divided by 10.  So, I typed the number 10 in any cell, Edit > Copy that number.  Select your numbers you'd like to alter.  Right-click the number (making sure they're all still selected) and choose Paste Special.  Choose Divide as the option.

That takes a number such as 720 and makes it 72.0  If you need 720 to become 7.20 then type 100 in any cell instead of the 10 we did earlier and voila.